# AutoMapper Custom Mappings

Tags: c#

Lets assume I have the following classes

```
public class foo
{
    public string Value;
}


public class bar
{
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
}
```

Now I want to configure Auto Map, to Map Value1 to Value if Value1 starts with "A", but otherwise I want to map Value2 to Value.

This is what I have so far:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<foo,bar>()
    .ForMember(t => t.Value, 
        o => 
            {
                o.Condition(s => 
                    s.Value1.StartsWith("A"));
                o.MapFrom(s => s.Value1);
                  <<***I want to throw Exception here***>>
            })
```

However I know how can I give value 1 or value 2 on Conditional basis but don't know how to put some custom code , call a function or throw an Exception

Please Guide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to `ResolveUsing`:

```
.ForMember(f => f.Value, o => o.ResolveUsing(b =>
    {
        if (b.Value1.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            return b.Value1;
        }
        return b.Value2;
    }
));
```

Comment: I don't want to give the reference to memory so I cant use ResolveUsing , is there any option to use the same thing with MapFrom ?

Comment: What do you mean by "give the reference to memory"?

Comment: ResolveUsing uses the Reference where as MapFrom uses the Value of the property being mapped.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand - `MapFrom` is designed to map straight from properties (it still pulls the _value_ from the _reference_ to the object being mapped from), while `ResolveUsing` is designed to allow virtually _any_ mapping logic.

Comment: there is a mistake in "if (b.Value1.StartsWith("A"));)".
(excessive symbols in the end)

Comment: Since Version 8 of AutoMapper, `ResolveUsing` is now integrated into `MapFrom`: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing