# Automapper convert multiple properties into array/list

Tags: c#, automapper

Our database is structured with properties like firstname1 and firstname2

Unfortunately I am unable to modify the database so I am wanting to at least return a list of firstnames.. how can I get automapper to turn

```
public class dto 
{
  public string firstname1;
  public string firstname2;
}
```

Into an array of

```
public class viewmodel 
{
  public string firstname;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper Custom Mappings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196367/automapper-custom-mappings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to `ResolveUsing`:

```
.ForMember(f => f.Value, o => o.ResolveUsing(b =>
    {
        // Combine your firstnames here...
        return new[]{ b.firstname1, b.firstname2 };
    }
));
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant.. looking to turn the properties into an array.. not concatenate them

Comment: Change the implementation.

Comment: ResolveUsing did not work, since it did not have access to the destination but doing same thing with MapFrom worked, accepting as it lead me to the right solution

Comment: @csharpdev in your edit reason, it would have been better to add that the reason for the change was due to the comments (reviewers can't see them directly in the review queue, it might be interpreted as just changing someone else's answer for no reason, and may lead to rejections)